# Is ModSecurity intended for authentication or WAF?

Tags: mod-security

What's the designed purpose of modsecurity for Apache/Nginx?

Does it play the role of authentication (Basic/Forms/Cookie)?

From my research, it appears to be a Web Application Firewall feature. The features like Authentication are best left to the native [web-server authentication functionality](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) like [mod_auth_basic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) or the [application framework security components](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html).

Researched Sources

- https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/modsecurity-comprehensive-guide/
- https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModSecurity is a *web application firewall* (WAF). It is not used for authentication.

> [What exactly is ModSecurity?](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/ModSecurity-Frequently-Asked-Questions-%28FAQ%29#What_exactly_is_ModSecurity)
>
> ModSecurity™is an open source, free web application firewall (WAF)
> Apache module. - - WAFs are deployed to establish an external security
> layer that increases security, detects and prevents attacks before
> they reach web applications. It provides protection from a range of
> attacks against web applications and allows for HTTP traffic
> monitoring and real-time analysis with little or no changes to
> existing infrastructure.

The FAQ on [What type(s) of security models does ModSecurity support?](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/ModSecurity-Frequently-Asked-Questions-%28FAQ%29#what-types-of-security-models-does-modsecurity-support) lists four security models: *Negative Security Model*, *Positive Security Model*, *Virtual Patching* & *Extrusion Detection Model*.